# Multiple Inheritance -> Interface1 reference calling methods of another interface2 in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
//Interface I1 and I2 I cant change as they are 
public interface I1
{
    void Display();
}
public interface I2
{
    void Display();
    void Display2();
}

//I can make changes here
public class MyClass : I1, I2
{
    void I1.Display()
    {
    }
    void I2.Display()
    {
    }

    void I2.Display2()
    {
        
    }
}

//Calling this method from a diffrent class
void processData(I1 data) //I have to accept I1 interface refrence only
{
    var temp = data.Display2(); //Error 
}
```

In processData() method data.Display2() is giving error. How I can achive as data is basically MyClass  object then how can I call Display2() with I2 reference.  Is there any solution like Casting or any SOLID principle which I am missing

Comment: You are attempting to call an interface method on an interface that you don't have access to. Why can't you overload procesData() to accept I2 or an instance of MyClass?

Comment: But data parameter is a object of MyClass class. Can we do casting and achieve it ?

Comment: You are passing in an Animal instance and attempting to use it as a derived Dog isntance.

Comment: ((I2)data).Display2(); Will this work ?

Comment: Not when the formal parameter is I1

Comment: "But data parameter is a object of MyClass class". It is not, you would have to pass in an instance of MyClass as data. As it stands now, data is I1 which MyClass just so happens to implement. processData(I1) does not know anything about MyClass.

Comment: MyClass mc = new MyClass();
processData(mc); 

and Doing ((I2)data).Display2();  I am able to call the method. Is this a valid solution?

Comment: ^^That is a workable solution, however, you stated in your original question that you could not change the formal parameter of the processData() method.

Comment: MyClass m = new MyClass();
processData(m);
void processData(I1 data)
{
    ((I2)data).Display2();
}

Comment: processData(I1 data) I have not changed

Comment: Rushee -Glad it worked for you. In 25 years of coding, I have never seen construct like this. It would likely be labeled an anti-pattern or very hard to follow code. I would definitely comment it as such :/

Answer (score 0):

Interface `I1` that is passed as a parameter to the `processData` method does not have method definition for `Display2` method. This will cause the error to be thrown. This is true, even if an instance of `MyClass` is sent as an input to `processData` method since the class will be cast to `I1` interface, as defined by the input to that method.

If the intent is to invoke the method on `I2` with processData method, can you change the signature of that method to accept `I2` interface as input parameter? If changing the signature is not an option for some reason, a "hacky" solution would be to check if the input implements `I2` interface & cast the input to that interface inside the method, something like

```
I2 myObj = data as I2
if (myObj != null) {
  myObj.Display2()
}
```

Comment: Ok. Cant we do casting ?

Comment: This is casting the object
```I2 myObj = data as I2```

Comment: ((I2)data).Display2(); what do you think about it ?

Comment: This will work, expect if input passed to the `processData` does not implement `I2` interface, then the code will throw runtime error. Casting and checking for null would help in preventing such an error

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
processData(mc);
void processData(I1 data)//I have to accept I1 interface reference only
{
    ((I2)data).Display2(); // Casting -> no error
}
```

Doing the casting solved my issue